# /.craft commands not running from root

Tags: craft3

I can't run /.craft commands and get the following error:

```
Craft can’t connect to the database. Check your connection settings.    

Unknown command: image-optimize/optimize/create
Caused by: Exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "image-optimize/optimize/create".'

in /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:543

Stack trace:
#0 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(181): yii\base\Module->runAction('image-optimize/...', Array)
#1 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(89): yii\console\Application->runAction('image-optimize/...', Array)
#2 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(148): craft\console\Application->runAction('image-optimize/...', Array)
#3 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\console\Request))
#4 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/craft(43): yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main}
```

I can connect to the database without issue and browse the site and admin console so I'm not sure why I get the error.

**Already tried:**

- hard coding the database values in db.php file but get the same error
- we're using .env.php files instead of .env so I checked that the executable is correctly defined in the craft file in the root
- I have ticked 'allow network access to MySQL' in MAMP under services > MySQL
- I have made sure the recommended settings for MAMP are in place from the [knowledge base article](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/mamp-with-composer-and-mysql-on-the-command-line) to ensure MAMPs PHP executable is being used and MYSQL server

**Additional info:**

- Craft CMS: 3.6.11.2
- PHP version: 7.4.12
- Database driver & version: MySQL 5.7.32
- Plugins & versions: Image Optimize 1.6.30
- Setup: MAMP

***Console Logged Output***

```
2021-05-04 14:30:03 [-][-][-][error][craft\db\Connection::open] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
2021-05-04 14:30:03 [-][-][-][error][craft\db\Connection::open] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
2021-05-04 14:30:03 [-][-][-][error][craft\base\ApplicationTrait::getIsDbConnectionValid] There was a problem connecting to the database: Craft CMS can’t connect to the database with the credentials in config/db.php.
2021-05-04 14:30:03 [-][-][-][error][craft\errors\DbConnectException] PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:712
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(712): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root', Array)
#1 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(631): yii\db\Connection->createPdoInstance()
#2 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Connection.php(152): yii\db\Connection->open()
#3 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(822): craft\db\Connection->open()
#4 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(296): craft\console\Application->getIsDbConnectionValid()
#5 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/App.php(592): craft\console\Application->getIsInstalled()
#6 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/app.php(241): craft\helpers\App::projectConfigConfig()
#7 [internal function]: {closure}()
#8 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(631): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#9 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->invoke(Object(Closure), Array)
#10 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Object(Closure))
#11 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(748): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('projectConfig', true)
#12 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(158): yii\base\Module->get('projectConfig', true)
#13 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(1295): craft\console\Application->get('projectConfig')
#14 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(1466): craft\console\Application->getProjectConfig()
#15 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(1419): craft\console\Application->_setTimeZone()
#16 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(46): craft\console\Application->_preInit()
#17 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\console\Application->init()
#18 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(212): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#19 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(90): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#20 [internal function]: yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#21 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(420): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#22 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(171): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\console\\A...', Array, Array)
#23 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\console\\A...', Array, Array)
#24 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php(246): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#25 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/console.php(51): require('/Users/danlee/S...')
#26 /Users/danlee/Sites/galileo-servd/craft(42): require('/Users/danlee/S...')
#27 {main}
```

Comment: How are you running your setup? Looks like you’re in a Mac? Docker? MAMP? Homebrew? etc

Comment: @RitterKnight This is on MAMP - I know I know

Comment: @DanLee If it's MAMP Pro, have you ticked 'allow network access to MySQL' under services > MySQL

Comment: @dmatthams No I haven't - that doesnt seem to get rid of the MySQL error.

Comment: @DanLee try also changing host from localhost -> 127.0.0.1

Comment: From what I recall, you have to jump through a few extra hoops for MAMP to connect to the database from the CLI: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/mamp-with-composer-and-mysql-on-the-command-line

Comment: @BradBell thanks for your comment - I have made sure everything is in place from that knowledge base article. I still get the error.

Comment: @dmatthams that seemed to do the trick! Setting DB_SERVER' => '127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

To remedy the issue here is some more detail on top of Craft's [Knowledge Base Article](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/mamp-with-composer-and-mysql-on-the-command-line) at Craft on setting up MAMP with Craft CMS:

1. You want to ensure you are using the MAMP PHP executable and MAMP MySQL Server

Create bash file in your user folder

`touch ~/.bash_profile`

Add the following to the top (make sure you change the PHP version to match *Craft Control Panel > Utilities > PHP Info*):

`export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.27/bin:${PATH}"`

2. Ensure the Database server is set to '127.0.0.1' and not 'localhost'
3. Tick '*Allow network access to MySQL*' in MAMP under *Services > MySQL*
4. run `source ~/.bash_profile`
5. restart MAMP server and try running a `/.craft` command (in my case it was `./craft image-optimize/optimize/create`)